# option 4 exits the program without do the intended function

Tags: lua

I'm writing a program on the computercraft minecraft mod and whenever I try option 4 it exits the program without doing anything:

```
os.pullEvent = os.pullEventRaw
while true do
term.clear()
term.setCursorPos(1,1)
print ("Welcome to F-SecOS")
print ("1)initialize")
print ("2)shutdown")
print ("3)power control")
print ("4)rednet control")

input = io.read()



if input == "1" then
 term.clear()
 term.setCursorPos(1,1)
 print ("intitializing 10%")
 print ("|")
 sleep(1)
 term.clear()
 term.setCursorPos(1,1)
 print("initializing 25%")
 print("/")
 sleep(1)
 term.clear()
 term.setCursorPos(1,1)
 print("initializing 50%")
 print("--")
 sleep(1)
 term.clear()
 term.setCursorPos(1,1)
 print("initializing 75%")
 print(".\.")
 sleep(1)
 term.clear()
 term.setCursorPos(1,1)
 print("initializing 90%")
 print("|")
 sleep(1)
 term.clear()
 term.setCursorPos(1,1)
 print("initializing 100%")
 print("/")
 sleep(1)
 term.clear()
 term.setCursorPos(1,1)
 print("F_sec initialized")
 sleep(1)
 term.clear()
 term.setCursorPos(1,1)
 print("F_SecOS V1.8")
 break
 end

if input == "2" then
 os.shutdown()
 end

if input == "4" then
 break
  end

if input == "3" then
while true do 
 term.clear()
 term.setCursorPos(1,1)
 print("1)open outer door")
 print("2)close outer door")
 print("3)open inner door")
 print("4)close inner door")
 print("5)open middle door")
 print("6)close middle door")
 print("q)exit")
 CI = io.read()
 if CI == "1" then
  rs.setOutput("left",true)
  end

 if CI == "2" then
  rs.setOutput("left",false)
  end 

 if CI == "3" then
  rs.setOutput("right",true)
  end

 if CI == "4" then
  rs.setOutput("right",false) 
  end

 if CI == "5" then
  rs.setOutput("bottom",true)
  end

 if CI == "6" then
  rs.setOutput("bottom",false)
  end



if CI == "Q" or CI == "q" then
  break
  end 


  if input == "4" then
 term.clear()
 term.setCursorPos(1,1)
 print ("1)open ports")
 print ("2)close ports")
 print ("3)send message")
 print ("4)unused function")
 print ("5)unused function")
 print ("q)exit")
 RI = io.read()


  if RI == "1" then
   rednet.open ("top")
   end

  if RI == "2" then
   rednet.close ("top")
   end

  if RI == "q" or RI == "Q" then
   end
  end
 end
end
end
```

the problem is rednet control isn't working I input 4 and the program ends without doing anything doesn't clear the screen or print the text and I've tried everything I know to fix it but the same problem keeps occuring or I get an error message

by the way the reason there no while true do in rednet controll is because bring up a whole new set of issues

Comment: Please format and indent your code properly.

Comment: And additionally simplify it so that we can find the problem faster.

Answer (score 0):

You have this chunk of code in the middle:

```
if input == "4" then
 break
  end
```

between input 2 and 3, so it is catching the input here and stopping before it gets to the end of the code where you also have another `if input == "4"` with the actual logic of what you want to do.